# how to access annotation of an property(class,mappedBy,inversedBy)

Tags: symfony

Good morning,

Is it exist an function where I pass an entity and the propertyName and return me the mappedBy,inversedBy and absoluteClassName of an Entity.
The goal is to use the __call to create automatic getteur/setteur and addFucntion bidirectionnal.
I don't want to use generates Entities I want all getteur,setteur and add Function use __call.
But i can"t do an addBirectionnal if i don't know if the relation is many to many or one to many and if i don't know the name of the mappedBy.

my code:

```
 public function __get($p){
        return $this->$p;
    }
    public function __set($p,$v){
        $this->$p = $v;
        return $this;
    }

     public function __call($name,$arguments){
        if(substr($name,1,3)=='et')
            $name2 = substr(3);
            if($name[0] == 'g'){
                return $this->$name2;
            }else{//substr($name,0,1) == 's'
                $this->$name2 = $arguments[0];
                /*for a one to one*/
                /*$mappedByName= getmappedByOrInversedBy(get_class($name),$name2);
                if($mappedByName){
                     $this->$name->$mappedByName = $this;/
                }*/
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need getmappedByOrInversedBy, thanks.

edit: I try this

```
 public function test(){
        $str = "AppBundle\Entity\Group";
        $mapping = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo($str);
        $d = $mapping->getAssociationMappedByTargetField('trad');
        var_dump($d);

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ));
    }


class Group
{
     ...

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Traduction",inversedBy="grp")
    */
    protected $trad;
}
```

Result : Undefined index: trad

Comment: Please try my edit, it works now (I've tried, I don't know why ClassMetadataInfo doesn't work)

Comment: Yes, thanks, using $em works fine, I think I will make a parent Entity that have an entity Manager I set Before each Conctroler.

Comment: You can inject the EntityManager in your entity but it's not ideal. I will open a question to know why ClassMetadataInfo('namespace') doesn't work in Symfony, because it works fine in a standalone doctrine project and in other contexts. See this thread which implement a custom and light MappingDriver which can allow you to access metadata within your entiy : http://afsy.fr/avent/2013/10-les-meta-donnees-doctrine

Comment: Ok, what is the alternative ?
I am not sure it will be considered like an issue because on documentation they said the only reason these functions are public are for speed.

Comment: A MappingDriver seems to be an alternative for get the metadata within your entites. See http://afsy.fr/avent/2013/10-les-meta-donnees-doctrine
Otherwise, pass the entityManager to your entity when calling methods from controller, or make your entity as a service and inject the EntityManager into (See dependency injection and services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ClassMetadataInfo](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php) is what you are looking for.

Creates an instance with the entityName :

```
$mapping = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo($entityNamespaceOrAlias);
```

Then, get the informations you want :

Get all association names:  `$mapping->getAssociationNames();`

Get the join column of an association:
`$mapping->getSingleAssociationJoinColumnName($fieldName);`

Get the mappedBy column of an association:
`$mapping->getAssociationMappedByTargetField($fieldName);`

...

Look at the class to know which method you can access.
Hopes it's what you expect.

**EDIT**

As you can access the `EntityManager` (i.e. from a controller), use :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:Group');
```

To be sure there is no problem with your entity namespace, try :

```
print $metadata->getTableName();
```

To retrieve the associations of the entity, use :

```
$metadata->getAssociationNames();
```

And to get the mapping informations of an existing association, use :

```
$metadata->getAssociationMapping($fieldName);
```

And to get all the association mappings of your entity, use:

```
$metadata->getAssociationMappings();
```

Comment: Browse the following documentation to know all you can do with this class:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html

Comment: I try with namespace alias, stin not string but i always have an emty array width the function getAssociationNames.


 $str = "AppBundle\Entity\TraductionAppBundle\Entity\Group";
        $mapping = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo($str);
        $d = $mapping->getAssociationMappedByTargetField('trad');
        var_dump($d);

Comment: It takes only one classname as argument (string) like new ClassMetadataInfo('AppBundle\Entity\Group');

Comment: Yes it is what i have done, I have edit my subject to show what I have test.
the resultat is undefined index ''

Comment: Try $mapping->getAssociationMapping('trad'); and getFieldMapping('trad')

Comment: I get No mapping found for field 'trad' on class 'AppBundle\Entity\Group'.
If i reverse inversedBy and mappedBy it is the same.

Comment: Try getAssociationNames, and if it doesn't work change the namespace to $str = 'AppBundle:Group'

Comment: no it change nothing does this work on your computer ? I get an empty Array

Comment: Is your entity and associations working properly ? It seems you have a problem in your mapping. Try on another entity or get the full mapping and debug

Comment: I've edited my answer, please try the second alternative to retrieve the metadata.